# i have faced a problem in search for arabic work inside an array

Tags: php, strpos, elasticsearch-php

Hi everyone i have faced a problem during my working to return a response for a api
the main problem is

```
$name = "تش";
$restaurants =   [
  "تشك تشيكن",
  "بيتزا ساخنة",
  "كينتاكي",
  "تشيكن سبوت"
];

foreach ($restaurants as $restaurant) {
  if (strpos($restaurant, $name)) {
    echo "founded";
  }
}
```

any help ?

Comment: What **exactly** is your problem with this code?

Comment: the problem was when search for a letter or a word in an array item no response but i found the problem and i fix it

Answer (score 1):

Your first argument should be `$item` and then the keyword you are searching for which is `$search`

So your code should look like:

```
$item = "أهلا وسهلا بكم";
$search = "وسهلا";
if (strpos($item, $search)){
    echo "founded";
}else {
    echo "not founded";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument in [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) should be the `haystack`, which is the string you want to search in, and the second argument is the `needle`, which is the string you want to search for

```
    <?php
    
    $item = "أهلا وسهلا بكم";
    $search = "وسهلا";

     // look if $search is in $item
    if (strpos($item, $search)){
       echo "founded";
    }else {
    echo "not founded";
    }
```

https://3v4l.org/C07o8

Answer (score 0):

based on this [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935259/php-arabic-text-compare-using-strpos), Arabic characters are encoded using multibyte characters, so you need to use `grapheme_strpos()`

```
if (function_exists('grapheme_strpos')) {
    $pos = grapheme_strpos($tweet, $keyword);
} elseif (function_exists('mb_strpos')) {
    $pos = mb_strpos($tweet, $keyword);
} else {
    $pos = strpos($tweet, $keyword);
}
```

Comment: That's not the issue. The order of the arguments are incorrect, as others mentioned. The position is irrelevant if the intention is to find a sequence of characters.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer finally

```
   $name = "تش";
    $restaurants =   [
      "تشك تشيكن",
      "بيتزا ساخنة",
      "كينتاكي",
      "تشيكن سبوت"
    ];
    
    foreach ($restaurants as $restaurant) {
      if (strpos($restaurant, $name) !== false) {
        echo "founded";
      }
    }
```